# turtlebot3 low battery beeping

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! To preface, I am running ros on a turtlebot3 using Ubuntu 16.02. I am wondering where I can change the turtlebot's source code so that it does *not* beep when the battery is low. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296145/turtlebot3-low-battery-beeping/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @AmateurHour,

The buzzer you mentioned is equipped with OpenCR, the main controller of TurtleBot3. OpenCR checks the voltage of the battery and when the voltage is below 11V, the buzzer sounds. If you do not want to use it, you can modify the turtlebot3_diagnosis.cpp part of OpenCR. The related code is the link below.

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/blob/df6f6dcfacc6f400083210495a8f944728bf70d6/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_diagnosis.cpp#L259-L288

Please refer to the link below for the information needed for this modification. :)

- Setting the Arduino IDE for OpenCR
  http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/opencr_setup/#arduino-ide
- How to modify ROS library code (OpenCR)
  http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/appendix_opencr1_0/#how-to-modify-ros-library-code

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-03**:
Fantastic, thank you!!

**Comment by [rodrigo55](https://answers.ros.org/users/53015/rodrigo55/) on 2021-10-04**:
Hi @Pyo,

I am also interested in making this modification. My Arduino IDE is setup for OpenCR already, and I have found the file I'm supposed to modify according to the last link:

In my case, the path is

~/.arduino15/packages/OpenCR/hardware/OpenCR/1.4.18/libraries/turtlebot3/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_diagnosis.cpp

I have made the changes in the code to stop the low voltage alarm, but **how do I sent the modified file to the OpenCR?** Do I need to upload it somehow? Run the bootloader?

I can't just use arduino to upload it to the board because it is a .cpp file

Please help! Thanks.

**Comment by [Will Son](https://answers.ros.org/users/32218/will-son/) on 2021-10-14**:
You could use Arduino IDE to upload the modified firmware.
https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/issues/286#issuecomment-943874988